# Получение доступа к библиотеке с помощью ctypes

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes

Каким образом я могу вызвать экспортируемые функции из библиотеки (не dll формата) прямо и процесса?

Comment: Можете привести код, который экспортирует указанную библиотеку в Ваш процесс?

Comment: Михаил, не могу, кода у меня нет. Но я знаю, что функции этой библиотеки используются другой библиотекой и я знаю, что делает функция, которая мне нужна. Мне нужно получить доступ к функции, при этом с помощью ctypes.LibraryLoader библиотека вроде как загружается (по крайней мере ошибки нет). Только не понятно, куда загружается эта библиотека и мне нужно не загружать ее, а получить к ней уже загруженной доступ из процесса.

Comment: Ваша ОС Windows?

Comment: Да, у меня Windows 10.

Comment: LibraryLoader же даёт Вам объект библиотеки? Не пробовали через него вызвать функцию? Типа lib = ctypes.LibraryLoader result_action = lib.name_method(args)

Comment: Завершается с ошибкой: TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: Вот тут куча примеров: https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/102416/ctypes.windll.LoadLibrary